# Blue light blinking despite no notification

Tags: notification-led

On my phone, the blue  light is blinking. However I have no notification. What could explain the blue  light?

I use on Android 6.0 with LG G4.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that an app could be configured to control the notification light (and color)? I had set up Signal to make it light blue when there are new unread messages.

Comment: @U.Windl thanks, yes indeed I've seen different notification colors. But typically it's accompanied with a notification in the notification bar

Answer (score 1):

I just bought my Alcatel Idol 3- 5.5 just a week ago and I had this same problem. The way I fixed it was by doing a device reset (Setting- Backup&Reset-Device Reset) when I restarted my phone it prompted me to do a system update. I did that and the problem went away.No more flashing light!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Hopefully someone has less brutal solution :-)

Comment: this might help..To clear cache, shut down the phone. Then press volume up key, home button, and power button at the same time. This will boot you into a menu where one of the options is to clear cache. Do it, then restart. Hopefully that will fix the issue. Its a less brutal solution